# OpenApi Annotations causing double slash

Tags: php, swagger, openapi, openapi-generator, swagger-php

I'm using zircote/swagger-php to generated API documentation based on OpenApi annotations that I have added to existing code.

For the most part it's working fine, but I've noticed one strange bit. I have a method, `indexAction()`, that is supposed to return a list of items:

```
/**
 * @OA\Get(
 *      path="\location",
 *      description="Retrieves a list of locations for the current organisation",
 *      method="indexAction",
 *      @OA\Response(
 *          response="200",
 *          description="List of locations",
 *          @OA\JsonContent(
 *              type="array",
 *              @OA\Items(ref="#/components/schemas/Location")
 *          ),
 *          @OA\XmlContent(
 *              type="array",
 *              @OA\Items(ref="#/components/schemas/Location")
 *          )
 *      )
 * )
 */
public function indexAction()
{
```

After compiling the documentation json file, I open it and this action is listed as follows:

```
"paths": {
    "\\location": {
        "get": {
            "summary": "The index action handles index/list requests; it should respond with a\nlist of the requested resources.",
            "description": "Retrieves a list of locations for the current organisation",
            "operationId": "2b36ea7d6a6e350fd6c7564bc908a25b",
            "responses": {
                "200": {
                    "description": "List of locations",
                    "content": {
                        "application/json": {
                            "schema": {
                                "type": "array",
                                "items": {
                                    "$ref": "#/components/schemas/Location"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        "application/xml": {
                            "schema": {
                                "type": "array",
                                "items": {
                                    "$ref": "#/components/schemas/Location"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
```

For some reason the "path" is listed as `\\location` instead of, as I expect, `\location` - does anyone know why this is happening? I hope this is enough, if more code is required I can supply it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\\` is just an escaped version of the `\` character in JSON strings. That is, the actual value of the `"\\location"` string is `\location`.

However, URL paths use `/` forward slashes, and OpenAPI also requires that [paths start with `/`](https://spec.openapis.org/oas/v3.0.3.html#patterned-fields). So you need to replace

```
path="\location",
```

with

```
path="/location",
```